# Anything forward-thinking things to do regarding solar panels when putting a new roof on?

Tags: roof, solar-panels

If you were putting a new roof on now on a shed or garage, and solar panels were a real possibility in the next two or three years (for lights and light-duty electric tools), what things, if any, would you would do, in anticipation, to make the future solar-installation easier?

Comment: Look into solar shingles right now. It is the roof.

Comment: Photovoltaic or thermal for water heating?

Comment: If not adding them now, would use asphalt shingles instead of steel roofing.  Looked into it a few years ago, but company did not want to put them on a steel roof, did say roof was placed right.  Do not know why.  Do look into the solar shingles and any incentives where you live(taxes, rebates).

Comment: @JimStewart  : Edited the question, thanks for asking purpose.  Didn't think of that.

Comment: @crip659: I will look into solar shingles.

Answer (score 1):

I would be running the pipes to a suitable box ready. Just remember to blank them so insects don’t crawl in - slows the flow rate...

And fit, or mark the beams for fixings.

Comment: The solar panel crew are pretty good with hammer-resonating to locate the beams, but it's something I considered when I read the question. How to do that? Our install was done in 3 phases, each not considered at the time of the previous, so locating junction boxes was out. The neighbor did his all in one go, but they ran the conduit on the roof with standoffs! Yuck. Obviously not as qualified as our crew.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, in some regions this is code, running the pipes/conduits from roof to panel.

Comment: Well planned and done pipe should not look particularly worse than the rest of the installation.  If you have attic space back entry would be more tidy though.  The "Suitable box" can be in a space near the roof rather than on the roof.  A bank of spare conduits from the basement to the attic during rough in can be the most wonderful thing.

Comment: @Solar Mike: Are the spacings for mounting brackets standardized on solar panels?  Would it make sense to install the mounting hardware now?

Comment: @mrblint no - solar panels come from several manufacturers - much like cars, are they all the same size?